# Passing a Var from HTML Map

Tags: html, dictionary

I have an Image Map with links. There are 50 to 70 links on the Map. Instead of making many HTML Pages for each link. I was thinking I could create a blank HTML Page and pass a var from the Image Map. This would be like a fill in the blanks type of HTML Page. Is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="detail.htm?id=sun" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="detail.htm?id=mercury" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="detail.htm?id=venus" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: Yes but for the life of me I can not see how to add a var then pass it on. Would the Id do this. How does the blank HTML see this. Would blank HTML need each Id on the page.

Comment: There is where you get into programming. You would need something like PHP, Ruby, Nodejs or ColdFusion to make `detail.htm` smart enough to detail with the variations.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it.